# Writing an excel file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Hi I have the code above to write an excel file:

```py
def write_excel(df):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("PATH\output.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')  

    workbook=writer.book
    worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('sheet')
    writer.sheets['sheet'] = worksheet

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet', startcol = 0, startrow = 0)
    writer.save()

write_excel(df)
```

df is a dataframe looking like:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ\n\nhello you, hello\n
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF\n\nhello you, hello\n  
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH\n\nhello you, hello\n
```

but it writes an excel document with the following output:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF  
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH
```

Comment: What is your input `df`? Can you put a reproducible example?

Comment: Is `df` defined anywhere before you call `write_excel(df)`?

Comment: There is also a typo here PATH/output.xlsx"

Comment: `(PATH/output.xlsx"` - are you missing a double-quote character?

Comment: The error message clearly says that `df` is `None`.  Can you show us the section of code that creates the `df` variable?

Comment: Works for me - cannot reproduce.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: awesome its fixed thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'` is thrown because `df` you are passing to the function is `None`, but not DataFrame as you probably intended.
It is trying to call `.to_excell()` method of the `df` parameter passed, which does not exist since it is a `None`.

Try printing `df` at the beginning of the function to validate that.
To fix, investigate why the `df` is `None` and try to fix it to a proper `DataFrame`